# Woocommerce How to get Shipping address and Billing before checkout to calculate the shipping fees then add to the total amount

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I just need very simple hook that suitable for this kind of feature whichI saw many times.

I want to get the billing data and shipping data of woocommerce once the customer fill or change it to calculate the shipping fees then add to the total amount before checkout becuae CA shipping fees different from NY for example

I use `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` to review the order before checkout so I need something similar to work on input billing data fields and shipping fields.

```
function getcartitems()
{

    echo WC()->customer->get_billing_address_1();
    echo WC()->customer->get_billing_city();
    echo WC()->customer->get_billing_state();

    ?>
    <script>
        alert("Cart");
    </script>
<?php

    global $woocommerce;
    $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    
    $items1 = json_encode($items, true);

    $items1 = json_decode($items1, true);
    echo count($items1);

    file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'debug.txt', print_r($items, true));
    //file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'debug1.txt', print_r($order_data, true));
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'getcartitems', 12);
```

[image: wc]

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use an ajax call from the checkout page like so;

The hook that you should use for this is if you want to calculate shipping on the checkout pahe would be; `woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form`

Source: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/

```
// This should be added to your primary plugin file.
// Sometimes called functions.php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_country_fees', 'check_country_fees' );
```

Action Name (second parameter above) is what is passed below.

```
let data = {
    'action': 'check_country_fees',
    'country': document.getElementById('country_field').value,,
    'zip_code': document.getElementById('zip_code_field').value,
};

jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', data, function (response) {
     if (response.success === true) {
         // Handle Success
         let resp = JSON.parse(response.data.json_response);
         if (resp.success) {
             // Hanle Success Response
         }
    } else {
        alert(response.data);
    }
}).fail(function (response) {
    // Handle Error
    let resp = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
    alert('Error: ' + resp.data);
});
```

Finally, you would need to add an event listener on the page. You can likely call this on page load

```
function addEvtListenerToCheckoutPage() {
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DomContentLoaded', (event) => {
            document.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
                if (document.getElementById('country_field') !== "" &&
                    document.getElementById('zip_code_field) !== "") {
                    
                    // Insert jQuery.Post function here
                }
            })
        })
    <script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: When I use `woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form` it just prints the empty arrays of the fields before or after the billing form without the data for example `object(WC_Checkout)#2903 (3) { ["fields":protected]=> array(4) { ["billing"]=> array(11) { ["billing_first_name"]=> array(5) { ["label"]=> string(10) "First name" ["required"]=> bool(true) ["class"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "form-row-first" } ["autocomplete"]=> string(10) "given-name" ["priority"]=> int(10) } ["billing_last_name"]=> array(5) { ["label"]=> string(9) "Last name" ["required"]=> bool(true) ["class"]=>`

Comment: the overall hook it just display something after the shipping or billing div but doesn't send hook with the data when I insert data in the billing form

Comment: Thanks I got it, everything working except the function doesn't fire and can't get the data

Comment: ` let data = {
                        'action': 'check_country_fees',
                        'billing_first_name': document.getElementById('billing_first_name').value,
                    };
` 
`$billing_first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];

    echo $billing_first_name;`

which refer to the id that I need, I get the data of the input in alert but can't get it by the hook or the sending request.

Comment: I can try and replicate this tomorrow and send you exact code with explanation. I have a WP local host setup should be able help in a few hours! If you get it resolved first, kudos!

Comment: Ajax made successfully, but can't get the data and the action doesn;t fire, can I make the action fire on the same page? I tried to use`$(document).ready(function()` but still doesn't work I think this will be the last problem

Comment: You should be able to fire actions on the same page as long as you're calling the action correctly in the PHP for example; 

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_country_fees', 'check_country_fees' );`

Make sure you add `wp_ajax_` to the action name and then the name of your function after `wp_ajax_` and in the second argument. You then need to use the `check_country_fees` as the action in the ajax call.

Comment: I got it, the action fire successfuly also but for some reason `wp_ajax_check_country_fees` function all the data printed in the console instead of the server side.

Comment: Are you handling/updating shipping fees in the success response? What does the success response look like so far?

Comment: `if (response.success === true) {
         // Handle Success
         let resp = JSON.parse(response.data.json_response);
         if (resp.success) {
             // Hanle Success Response
         }
    } else {
        alert(response.data);
 // the success message here 
    }`

No I'm not handling the shipping fees in the success at all I would do it at the back-end but I can't receive the data on the back-end 
for example `add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_country_fees', 'check_country_fees' );` when this function runs, it runes in the console log not on the back-end.

Comment: `function  check_country_fees()
{
    global $wpdb;
    echo "testing callback";
    if (isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) {
        $billing_first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];
        $billing_first_name = json_decode($billing_first_name);
        extract($_POST);
        print_r($_POST);
        //testingajax($billing_first_name);
    } else {

        return 0;
    }
?>
    <script language="text\javascript">
        alert("test ajaxbilling name check country");
    </script>
<?php
}`

These confirmation messages and the data printed in the console.log

Comment: I suspect could because of `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event)` because I have another ajax call on the same localhost works properly.

Comment: Hmmm, DomContentLoaded shouldn't cause the issue, all it is doing is waiting for the page to load (completely) before adding the additional evt listener. Essentially, makes sure the complete DOM is loaded, so the elements you want to add listeners to exist. in the PHP function you could add a wp_send_json($data). Link: [https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/] and send json back to the browser as JSON. So where you have `print_r($_POST) try wp_send_json($_POST)

Comment: when I use `wp_send_json($data);` also it printed in the console and when I use `wp_send_json_success();` it prints true also in the console.

Comment: btw the whole code in the `index.php` file of the plugin

Comment: At this point I’m confused how the data is even getting to console unless you mean network tools within developer tools? If your getting data in network tools from the response, that’s what you need to retrieve in the response.success part of the jQuery

Comment: I even tested on the hosted WordPress website on Godaddy same result and changed to another ajax call still getting the result on the browser, I hope there is something to get the shipping data details of some Woocommerce hooks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the part of getting the data in network tools but it's the same thing on the host as well.

Comment: If using chrome, right click and select inspect, then click on "Network" tab and if you select on an object in the "Name" section, you should see server posts and responses.